# Problem configuring L3VPN with MPLS, RSVP-TE, VLAN

Tags: cisco, vlan, bgp, is-is, mpls-te

We are having problems to configure a L3VPN in VIRL with an MPLS CORE NETWORK that uses RSVP-TE as label exchange protocol and IS-IS as IGP protocol. The idea is to distinguish different type of traffic from the CEs to route them on specific MPLS tunnels. The topology is depicted in the following Figure.
[image: Topology]

-CE1 (ioS): belongs to autonomous system 2 (AS-2), it is attached to PE1 with a VLAN/802.1q connection and they use an eBGP session for IPv4 prefix advertisement.

-CE2 (ioS): belongs to AS-3, it is attached to PE2 with a VLAN/802.1q connection and an eBGP session for IPv4 prefix advertisement.

-PE1 and PE2 (XRv): belong to AS-1, they are connected through MPLS-TE tunnel and they use an MP-iBGP session for VPNV4 prefix advertisement.

-P1 and P2 (ioS): belong to AS-1, they are part of the MPLS core network.

-CE1 and CE2 belongs to the same VPN associated to VRF-A on the PEs. VRF-A is placed on a logical subinterface that connects CE1--PE1 and it uses the ip address of physical interface. The same method is used for the connection between CE2--PE2.

-CE1 is reachable from PE1 through VRF-A using physical interface ip address of CE-1 (same from PE2 to CE2).

-PE2 is reachable from PE1 through tunnel-te11 (dynamic config by RSVP-TE) and viceversa using the loopback interface.

-Problem: CE2 cannot reach CE1 and viceversa. We believe that there is an error or something missing in the configuration. Attached please find the configuration of all the routers hoping that someone can help us.

We have some doubts about the configuration:

- We use as update-source of eBGP session the logical subinterface on which the VRF-A stays. Is it possible to obtain the association between VRF and an MPLS tunnel that is created using loopback interface?
- Is it correct to configure the CE to redistribute the network between CE and PE through eBGP session?
- If the connection between CE--PE is done through a VLAN_ID, what are the IPv4 prefixes that PE can advertise in eBGP session? (redistributed connected?)
- It is possible to use a CE loopback interface to simulate a network behind the CE and propagate this prefix through eBGP?

Thanks in advance,

Best regards

Serena and Rodolfo

```
**PE1 CONFIGURATION**

!! IOS XR Configuration 6.1.2
!! Last configuration change at Mon Sep 18 09:11:00 2017 by cisco
 !

explicit-path name PATH
 index 1 next-address strict ipv4 unicast 10.0.0.10
 index 2 next-address strict ipv4 unicast 10.0.0.26
 index 3 next-address strict ipv4 unicast 10.0.0.18 
!
vrf VRF-A
 address-family ipv4 unicast
  import route-target
   1:101
  !
 export route-target
  1:101
  !
 !
!

interface Loopback0
 description Loopback
 ipv4 address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface tunnel-te11
 bandwidth 3000
 ipv4 unnumbered Loopback0
 priority 7 7
 autoroute announce
 !
 destination 192.168.1.2
 record-route
 path-option 1 dynamic
!

interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/0
 description to CE1
 ipv4 address 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.252
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/0.101
 vrf VRF-A
 ipv4 address 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.252
 encapsulation dot1q 101
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/1
 description to P1
 ipv4 address 10.0.0.9 255.255.255.252
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/2
 description to P2
 ipv4 address 10.0.0.5 255.255.255.252
!
route-policy bgp_in
  pass
end-policy
!
route-policy bgp_out
  pass
end-policy
!
router isis 1
 net 49.1921.6800.1001.00
 log adjacency changes
 address-family ipv4 unicast
  metric-style wide
  mpls traffic-eng level-2-only
  mpls traffic-eng router-id Loopback0
 !
 interface Loopback0
  passive
  circuit-type level-2-only
  address-family ipv4 unicast
  !
 !
 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/1
  circuit-type level-2-only
  point-to-point
 address-family ipv4 unicast
   metric 1
  !
 !
 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/2
  circuit-type level-2-only
  point-to-point
 address-family ipv4 unicast
  metric 1
  !
 !
!
router bgp 1
 bgp router-id 192.168.1.1
 address-family vpnv4 unicast
 !
 neighbor 192.168.1.2
  remote-as 1
  description iBGP peer PE2
  update-source Loopback0
  address-family vpnv4 unicast
   next-hop-self
  !
 !
 vrf VRF-A
  rd 1:1001
  label mode per-ce
  address-family ipv4 unicast
  !
  neighbor 10.0.0.1
   remote-as 2
   update-source GigabitEthernet0/0/0/0.101
   address-family ipv4 unicast
    route-policy bgp_in in
    route-policy bgp_out out
    as-override
   !
  !
 !
!
rsvp
 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/1
  bandwidth percentage 100
 !
 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/2
  bandwidth percentage 100
 !
!
mpls traffic-eng
 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/1
 !
 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0/2
!
!
end



**CE1 CONFIGURATION**

interface Loopback0
 description Loopback
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.255
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
description GigabitEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex full
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 description to PE1
 no ip address
 duplex full
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 mpls traffic-eng tunnels
 ip rsvp bandwidth percent 100
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2.101
 encapsulation dot1Q 101
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.252
!
router bgp 2
 bgp router-id 192.168.0.1
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 10.0.0.2 remote-as 1
 neighbor 10.0.0.2 update-source GigabitEthernet0/2.101
 !
 address-family ipv4
  network 10.0.0.0 mask 255.255.255.252
  neighbor 10.0.0.2 activate
 exit-address-family
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
```

**P1 CONFIGURATION**

```
interface Loopback0
 description Loopback
 ip address 192.168.1.3 255.255.255.255 
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 description to PE1
 ip address 10.0.0.10 255.255.255.252
 ip router isis 1
 duplex full
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 mpls traffic-eng tunnels
 isis network point-to-point 
 ip rsvp bandwidth percent 100
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
  description to P2
  ip address 10.0.0.25 255.255.255.252
  ip router isis 1
 duplex full
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 mpls traffic-eng tunnels
 isis network point-to-point 
 ip rsvp bandwidth percent 100
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 description to PE2
 ip address 10.0.0.13 255.255.255.252
 ip router isis 1
 duplex full
 speed auto
 media-type rj45
 mpls traffic-eng tunnels
 isis network point-to-point 
 ip rsvp bandwidth percent 100
!
router isis 1
 mpls traffic-eng router-id Loopback0
 mpls traffic-eng level-2
 net 49.1921.6800.1003.00
 is-type level-2-only
 metric-style wide
 passive-interface Loopback0
!
 ip forward-protocol nd
! 
!
```

Comment: "_We believe that there is an error or something missing in the configuration. Attached please find the configuration of all the routers hoping that someone can help us._" Where are the router configurations? Please edit your question to include those, otherwise we can only speculate or guess, and that is off-topic here.